# How to open the Sqlite database in vscode for flutter application?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I am working on a Flutter application with an underlying Sqlite database and I want to track the database on my physical device using VScode. In Android Studio, this can be done using the device explorer. However, I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish this in VScode without switching to Android Studio or using the ADB shell. Is there a solution that does not involve either of these options?

Comment: There's a command-line app called `sqlite3` for manipulating Sqlite databases, but sqlite is not designed for shared access, so you can't see live updates.

Comment: But with android studios device manager we can track the DB in live